# Generate sine wave to play middle C using PortAudio

Tags: audio, core-audio, portaudio, sound-synthesis

I am having trouble generating specific frequencies in PortAudio, whenever I try and change the frequency inside of the `sin(n * FREQ * 2 * PI / SAMPLE_RATE)` the frequency remains the same however the sound does seem to change in timbre, the higher the frequency value I put in there the uglier the sound, yet the same frequency.  This is what I have in my `patestCallback` loop:

```cpp
static int patestCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                           unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                           const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo,
                           PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                           void *userData )
{
   paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;
   float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;

   (void) timeInfo;
   (void) statusFlags;
   (void) inputBuffer;
   unsigned long n = 0;
   for(unsigned long i = 0; i<framesPerBuffer;i++,n++){
      float v = sin ( 261.626 * 2 * M_PI * ((float) n / (float) TABLE_SIZE) );
      *out++ = v;
      *out++ = v;
   }

   return paContinue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
static unsigned long n = 0;
```

You currently reset `n` in every function call, which leads to clicks at the begin of each new buffer and to those ugly sounds you hear. The more the period of the sine differs from the buffer length the uglier it sounds.

Comment: This suggestion should work (+1). Another solution might be to make n part of userData. This might be better in case you ever need to reset it externally or end up with multiple callbacks or something like that.

Comment: Yes, of course. Ideally, userData would be a struct or class containing the state of the actual audio engine.

Comment: Ok I put it all in a struct, it works beautifully thank you!... I think that I am having trouble conceptualizing how portaudio works, so does it continuously call patestCallback after each framesPerBuffer loop? Also, is it possible to write maybe 3 or 4 sine waves to the output so I can make chords?

Comment: Yes, sure just add several sines together with a different frequency each. However, the brute force sin() function is very expansive. There are way more efficient techniques to integrate a sine recursively.

Comment: Oh ok, that is the purpose of the table in most portaudio examples correct?